# Poor Django application degradation

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm assigned to support an old Django application. This application used to run on gunicorn synchronous workers. However, it was getting slower. Recently, a engineer made a change to use gunicorn asynchronous workers with *gevent*.

This week the system suffered a severe degradation when the number of HTTP requests increased. We received lots of `error: can't start new thread` on `gevent.threadpool._add_thread`. The Django view with most hits performs about 400 SQL queries before completing and renders a complex template.

Could the elevated number of queries and CPU time to render the template be playing badly with this new async worker? And if so, how can I explain it to others?

The connection pool is configured to not exceed the limit of postgres connections.

Comment: 400 queries is far too many. Can you share the view code so that we may help with that? If your app is optimized and the number of threads/workers cannot handle the load then you will need to scale your app

Comment: Remember that most of those queries require a round trip to your database and back to the web server, and even on the same switch, network I/O is a huge bottleneck. Have you used a tool like Django debug toolbar to look for duplicates that could be removed?

Comment: @IainShelvington

Yes the number of queries is too high. That was my argument before changing the worker type. However, the senior engineer kept arguing that the async worker would improve things. 

It is my limited understanding that the waiting list of handlers in gevent could potentialy grow large in such a scenario, is it correct?

Unfortunately I can't share the code.

Comment: @FlipperPA

Yes I have the toolbar enabled, but couldn't  convince the senior engineer to improve the SQL queries first. Thats the reason I am looking for more resources about gevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer instead of a comment because, while it can't address your situation, it does technically address your question. Also, there's just not enough room in a comment to ask for all the necessary clarification to get from one to the other.

> I'm assigned to support an old Django application. This application used to run on gunicorn synchronous workers. However, it was getting slower. Recently, a engineer made a change to use gunicorn asynchronous workers with gevent.

The deployment method is basically irrelevant to a Django app unless whoever wrote it was doing something that relies on synchronous request handling. For a few reasons, I would switch the deployment method back as a first step.

1. "An old Django application" suggests it's on a version that's out of support. If that's the case, it should not be public anyway, in which case traffic is almost certainly negligible.
2. "It was getting slower" needs an explanation. If it was somehow gaining cruft at a rate that noticeably impacted its responsiveness, *that* is the symptom you should start with.
3. Whoever switched from sync to async should provide their reasoning and explain their due diligence so you understand what they did to make sure they understood they weren't going to break this thing (and, if it's lacking, you might at least know what you don't have to look for).

> This week the system suffered a severe degradation when the number of HTTP requests increased. We received lots of error: can't start new thread on gevent.threadpool._add_thread. The Django view with most hits performs about 400 SQL queries before completing and renders a complex template.

400 queries per page points to either *really* poorly written code or, less likely, a whole lot of users viewing a phenomenally informative page that benefits not at all from any useful sort of caching. You mention "improv[ing] the SQL queries" in a comment, but Django's ORM is pretty decent about building queries, so hopefully you're just speaking generally; if whoever built this was writing SQL by hand and passing it through the ORM, that's certainly another potential area of concern.

It would be useful if you could provide information about the traffic volume the system was dealing well with previously and the volume it's now choking on. It'd also be good to know about your deployment; an autoscaling setup could mitigate this, though it'd also increase costs if you reconfigure it in a less efficient way, so that's a tradeoff.

> Could the elevated number of queries and CPU time to render the template be playing badly with this new async worker? And if so, how can I explain it to others?

If it were simply a matter of the app being overloaded by requests, the async deployment should actually help (or at least make database reads your bottleneck, but that's also extremely unlikely, since you're not reading from a SQLite file on a floppy).

> The connection pool is configured to not exceed the limit of postgres connections.

You have a whole different problem if you're hitting a DB connection limit. I think that's extremely unlikely.

Comment: Thanks Kungphu

I'll update my question latter with more information. But perhaps I can synthesize better my concerns:


The system does lots of heavy reporting rendering large PDF files (CPU Bound) on the application server. My concern was that due to excessive number of SQL queries one request that should be answered quickly gets interleaved with some of those reporting requests. By my limited understanding, async with gevent is pretty good when doing IO bound tasks, but not so great when mixing with CPU bound tasks.

Comment: Sure thing. It sounds like you might need to switch to an actual asynchoronous model, i.e. people say "I want this report" and provides an email address, and your Django app accepts the request, and a background task ([`celery`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery) may be a good choice) executes the task and ships the result to that inbox.